# Magento 2: How to move block into html div?

Tags: magento2.2.6, product-page, containers

I want to move below block in third "col-md-4 col-lg-4" div:-

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
    </container>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</block>
```

There is no separate container for `product.info` block.

My theme `catalog_product_view.xml` file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                <container name="product.info.col.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-4 col-lg-4" />
                <container name="product.info.col.main.wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-4 col-lg-4" />             
                <container name="product.info.addtocart.wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-4 col-lg-4" />                
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>   

        <move element="product.info.wrapper" destination="content" before="-" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.info.col.media"/>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.col.main.wrap"/>
        <move element="product.info" destination="product.info.addtocart.wrap" />       

        <referenceContainer name="product.info.price" remove="true"/>        
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="main.content" />
        <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="main.content" />
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title"/>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>

        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>        
        <move element="product.info.type" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="product.info.sku"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I also try below code as well but no luck

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info" htmlClass="col-md-4 col-lg-4" />
```

Any quick help would be appreciated. I need below layout on product page
[image] 
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: No. I am not able to find answer